# Paired Wilcoxon test with covariates in r

Tags: covariance, pairwise.wilcox.test

Is it possible to include covariates in paired wilcoxon tests? (E.g., data from multiple test points (1 group), needing to account for 1 variable).

Answer (score 0):

I just found https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultNonParam/MultNonParam.pdf, I don't know if it is useful.

[image]